# tapping one row will select multiple rows

Tags: select, ios5, tableview, rows

I have a weird issue in my tableview. I want to select rows and only want to show the checkmark. I have a tableview with multiple sections. Selecting the row and displaying the checkmark is fine, but 10 rows down the tableview, that row will also get selected??? When selecting more than one row, again, 10 lines down, multiple selections appear.

I am using:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:NO];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        // Reflect selection in data model
    } else if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        // Reflect deselection in data model
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not another row being selected, that's the same check-marked cell being reused. In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` you are using the cell to store state. In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you are not addressing whether the row should have a check mark or not.

What you will likely want to do is have an `ivar` `NSMutableSet` and in `didSelectRow..` either add or remove the `indexPath` from the set, depending on it's checked status. Then in `cellForRow..` set the `accessoryType` property based on the `indexPath`'s membership in the set.

**Edit** Sorry I didn't catch the comments where you save the state to in a data model. In that case all you have to do is add the check in `cellForRow...`. Since this is a common question I'll leave the original answer up.